# How can we add client certificate in our android project

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I have created the WCF Service and implement the Transport security with credential type "Certificate".
Now my client-side is an Android User app, how can we add a Client certificate in our app that can make a Secure Connection between the Android app and WCF. I am new, please anyone can guide me.

Comment: Assume that a competent attacker can de-compile your android apk and extract any certificate. So what extra security would that provide?

Comment: You do not add the certificate to the application.  You install the certificate on machine.  See : https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/212869927-How-to-install-Securly-SSL-certificate-on-Android-device-

Comment: You can refer to this link for information about how the WCF service securely communicates with the Android application: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45f62086-7800-48c5-afbe-e2ff7f28dbe6/using-certificates-with-wshttpbinding-to-secure-iphone-android-and-windows-phone-over-message?forum=wcf